# Laravel CSRF Token Mismatch on some pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have this javascript file that runs every 8 seconds calling the route `/ajax?act=notifications_show`. I have noticed that in some on the pages the javascript file would work fine but when visiting some pages it would show up an error such as `CSRF token mismatch`. I am not really sure why this happens but the pages have same layouts that I have extended.

Note that I already have added `<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>` for every layout

Notification.js

```
function get_notifications(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: window.location.origin + "/ajax?act=notifications_show",
    }).done(function( d ) {
        console.log("d: "+ d);
        // n = jQuery.parseJSON(d); //if error abort all commands below
        // console.log("n: "+ n);
        // //console.log(n.qqq);
        // $('#header_notification_bar').html(n.notification);
        // //alert(n.qqq);
        // if(n.has_noti == 1){
        //  toastr.info('<div><a href="#" onclick="toggle_comments('+n.id+')">'+n.noti_msg+' from '+n.noti_from+'</a></div>');
        // }        
    });
}
function toggle_comments(id){   
    $('body').toggleClass('page-quick-sidebar-open');
    $('#msg_contents').html('');
    get_chat_area(id);
    get_comments(id);
}
window.onload = function(e){    
    $('.dropdown-quick-sidebar-toggler').click(function (e) {   
        $('body').toggleClass('page-quick-sidebar-open');   
        $('#msg_contents').html('');
        get_chat_area(this.id);
        get_comments(this.id);
    }); 
    setInterval(get_notifications, 8000);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

Error showing
`message: "CSRF token mismatch." trace: [{,…}, {file: "C:\xampp7\htdocs\vms\app\Exceptions\Handler.php", line: 53, function: "render",…},…]`

[Gif Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qDdQj3ekRJ6w9qUPiB6XdtigZAyHpBYA/view?usp=sharing)

My questions are:
Why do errors show up on some pages but works on other pages?
How do I solve this issue when there are token mismatches?

Comment: any reason this is a POST route?

Comment: Re generate your token

Comment: @lagbox To be honest this project was pure php code which is just handed to me. I have only converted the raw PHP files to laravel so there are some codes that I'm not sure why they have implemented that way.

Comment: @kingneo do I regenerate token for every `window.load` or only if there is error such as csrf token mismatch?

Comment: Generate your project key clear cache

Comment: Also check your http request if it's sending your token

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, I was wrong not all pages have the meta tag for csrf. I have assumed that my fellow developer followed my implementation but it seems he did not use my extension that's why its showing error on some pages.

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```